# SQL count occurrences of a column in some other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count the occurrences of a column of table A to table B.

This query generates the first table

**Table A**

```
select geo_address_id 
from favourite_address    
where rider profile_id = 1;


geo_address_id
--------------
     2
     8
     4
```

The second table looks like this

**Table B**

```
rider_profile_id | geo_addresses| counter
-----------------------------------------
        1              8             3
        1              2             3
        1              6             2
        1              4             2
        1              1             1
        1              5             1
```

geo_address and geo_address_id are referring to the same thing.

I want to count the occurrences of the `geo_addresses_id` in the second table and end up with something like that

**Table C**

```
geo_addresses | counter
-----------------------
      8
      2
      4
```

ordered desc

I tried to joined the tables in the geo_addresses but I got some ambiguous errors.

Answer (score 1):

You just need `join` and `group by`:

```
select fa.geo_address_id, count(b.geo_address_id)
from favourite_address fa left join
     b
     on a.geo_address_id = b.geo_addresses
where fa.rider_profile_id = 1 
group by fa.geo_address_id;
```

If you qualify *all* column references in a query, you will never have a problem with ambiguous column references.  So, qualifying column references is a good practice.

Comment: It didnt work i am getting ERROR:missinf FROM-clause entry from table fav_geo_addresses. I created a view for fa.

Comment: @MarkosTzetzis . . . Th query looks well-formed to me, you just need to be careful about the table names.